# how to sum the column and get the rows based on month and year

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

It is my table can i get result for this .
Each user have points,i have to show  number of user points got in current month,current year

Thanks.

```
--------------------------------
| userId | points | date       |
--------------------------------
| 1      | 5      | 8/25/2013  |
| 1      | 3      | 8/16/2013  |
| 1      | 2      | 8/01/2013  |
| 1      | 2      | 9/25/2013  |
| 1      | 5      | 8/25/2013  |
| 1      | 3      | 2/16/2012  |
| 2      | NULL   | NULL       |
| 2      | NULL   | NULL       |
--------------------------------
```

They result should be like :

```
---------------------------------------------------
| userId | CurrentMonthpoints | CurrentYearPoints |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1      | 15                 | 17                |
| 2      | NULL               | NULL              |
---------------------------------------------------
```

My request :

```
SELECT  userId, 
        (SELECT   sum(points)
            from tbl_points
            WHERE  PointsDate between '8/1/2013' and '8/31/2013') AS CurrentMonthPoints,
        (SELECT distinct SUM(points)
             from tbl_points
             WHERE PointsDate between '1/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' ) AS CurrentYearPoints
 from tbl_user_performance_points
```

But My query shows wrongly as :

```
---------------------------------------------------
| userId | CurrentMonthpoints | CurrentYearPoints |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1      | 15                 | 17                |
| 2      | 15                 | 17                |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select a.userID,
  a.points_sum_m as currentmonthpoints,
  b.points_sum_y as currentyearpoints
from (select userID, sum(points) as points_sum_m
   from tbl_points
   where month(date) = month(getdate())
   group by userID) a
inner join (select userID, sum(points) as points_sum_y
   from tbl_points
   where year(date) = year(getdate())
   group by userID) b
on a.userID = b.userID;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff780/12

Comment: As Zessx said Its too working fine without giving manual dates,thanks a lot

Comment: No problem! I made it this way so that you will not have to change the dates of your query every month, to the current month. This will keep it pulling the current month and year at all times.

Answer (score 0):

```
  with month_cte(userid,Current_Month) as
  (select userid,sum(Points)Current_Month from tbl_points
  where datepart(mm,PointsDate)=datepart(mm,getdate()) and datepart(YY,PointsDate)=datepart(yy,getdate()) group by userid)

   , year_cte(userid,Current_year) as
  (select userid,sum(Points)Current_Year from tbl_points
  where datepart(YY,PointsDate)=datepart(yy,getdate()) group by userid)

  select Distinct t.Userid, Current_Month, Current_Year From tbl_points T 
  left join month_cte mc on T.userid=mc.userid
  left join year_cte yc on t.userid=yc.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to correct your query replace it with this...

```
SELECT  userId, 
        (SELECT   sum(points)
            from tbl_points
            WHERE  PointsDate between '8/1/2013' and '8/31/2013' and userId= X.UserId) AS CurrentMonthPoints,
        (SELECT distinct SUM(points)
             from tbl_points
             WHERE PointsDate between '1/1/2014' and '12/31/2014' and userId = X.UserId) AS CurrentYearPoints
 from tbl_user_performance_points X
```

Comment: Amazingly Works well,half a day spent for this.Really time saved.additionally 'Select Distint Userid 'Thanks a Lot :):)

Comment: Thanks, glad to help, altho it solves your question, however this may not be the best way to do what you are doing.... give Chad's answer a try... I would go with his answer or something along that line.. it will perform better. I also +1'ed his answer to bring it to top.